# Id and Tag Selectors in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've tried to search this topic but it's kind of a hard topic to get the right keywords to find what I'm looking for.

What is the difference between `#menu-nav ul {...}` and `ul#menu-nav {...}` ?

I am currently working to make a inline-block nav menu in a Wordpress theme and here is the CSS producing the effects I want (ie removing list-style-type, creating blocks, centering them within their parent container, etc).

```
ul#menu-nav  {
margin:0 auto; 
padding:0;
}
#menu-nav li {
list-style-type:none; 
display:inline-block; 
width:118px; 
height:56px; 
color:white; 
border:1px solid black;
}
```

If I change the `ul#menu-nav {...}` to `#menu-nav ul` the `padding:0;` and `margin:0 auto` no longer overrides the User Agent stylesheet. Frankly, this makes me assume that my CSS is hacky and I am going about this wrong.

Any suggestions or help or references would help immensely! I'd like to understand fully why they produce different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul#menu-nav` and `#menu-nav ul` mean very different things.

`ul#menu-nav` means "the `ul` tag with the id "menu-nav".  (Which is kind of superfluous, since `id` needs to be unique anyway then it doesn't make a difference which element has it.  Unless I suppose the content is dynamic enough that there's a chance that `id` might be applied to different kinds of elements in different circumstances, but that's probably a confusing design anyway.)

Example:

```
<ul id="menu-nav"> <-- This is what's being selected
    <!-- any other content -->
</ul>
```

`#menu-nav ul` means "the `ul` tag(s) which are descendants of the element with the is "menu-nav".

Example:

```
<div id="menu-nav">
    <ul></ul> <-- This is what's being selected
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu-nav ul {...}
```

Means any `ul` inside a tag with `id="menu-nav"`

and

```
ul#menu-nav {...}
```

Means an `ul` with `id="menu-nav"`